# Typescript Typings definition errors

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings

I am currently having issues adding proper type definitions to my project. I am very new to typescript and am following the guidance of a book (called ASP.NET Core and Angular 2) in order to become more familiar with it so I apologize if I my question lacks clarity at all. Anyway, in my `index.d.ts` file, I am getting about 140 errors. A few of these errors which each show up many times are:

> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>   Property 'unscopables' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.

After some research, it looks like this may be a versioning issue however after playing with different versions of `core-js` and `typings` in my `package.json` file, I am still unable to resolve the issue. Please see my below for m `package.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "mylestone",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
        "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
        "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
        "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
        "systemjs": "^0.19.37",
        "typings" :  "^1.3.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
        "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.16",
        "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
        "typescript": "^1.8.10"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall" :  "typings install dt~core-js --global"
    }
}
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `typings` anymore, it's deprecated. install `@types/core-js` as devdependency. I do expect that probably won't clear all issues around your codebases though, might need to adjust tsconfig as well correctly.

Comment: thanks for the answer- this didnt directly solve my problem but lead me down the proper path. After switching to @types/core-js, I targets es6 instead of es5 in my tsconfig. This is what solved my issue. Accepted